# Which pesticide should I use for the orange trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, citrus, pesticide

My orange tree seems to have some disease. The leaves are bubbled and curled. Does anybody know the name of the disease? Which pesticide should I use to cure it?

[image]

Comment: Any chance an herbicide has been used in the area ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 Not really. The peach tree (which is about 10ft away from the orange tree) had a similar issue. I wonder if it is a same disease.

Comment: @ DSKim; More likely the peach is getting the same herbicide; It can drift a hundred feet.

Comment: Not citrus leaf miner, that hardly distorts leaves, and the silvery leaf surface is left

Answer (score 0):

Looks like citrus leaf miners.

https://www.organicgardener.com.au/blogs/cure-curly-citrus